# A Simple Sequence (405, 360, 0...)

Tags: word, sequence

The answer is a relevant word; no computer needed

*Numbers are approximate*

405, 360, 0, 180, 360, 270, 190, 360, 0, 0, 180…

405, 80, 190, 90, 360, 0

Comment: I can't shake one idea so I have to ask. Am I looking at rot13(gur nepyratgu bs pheirf va yrggref?) I at least think we're looking at rot13(ebgngvbaf) but your puzzles are always tricky do who knows? :)

Comment: @TwoBitOperation Yes (correct), this one is pretty basic; if it's a duplicate someone can close it.

Comment: I've never seen this puzzle type before, and frankly I can't quite close the deal on deciphering the sequence anyway.  Let's see if someone swoops in and gets it before I can figure it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number sequence is

> The sum of the degrees of all angles in each capital letter

For instance

> (Noting that 2 angles adding to a straight angle are always 180)
>  A = 2*(180) + ~ 45 = 405
>  B = 4*(90) = 360
>  C = no intersections = 0
>  D = 2*(90) = 180

The answer is

> **A** = 405
> **N** = 2*~40 = 80
> **G** = 90 + ~90 = 190?
> **L** = 90
> **E** = 4*90 = 360
> **S** = 0

Comment: Now the answer is known, the title is a clever one - those first three terms certainly do represent 'simple'! (At least according to [these guys](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ho7796-au8U)...)

Comment: Great work! Yeah, G was tricky as it varies widely depending on the font  : )